# Correlated Chance Constraint

Tags: optimization, correlation

If we want to satisfy the following constraint with the probability of 1-$\epsilon$:

$$
\mathcal{P}(a \leq x) \ge 1 - \epsilon
$$
where $x$ is the decision variable, $a$ is a random variable with a normal distribution $ N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, it is enough to have 
$$
x \geq \mu + \sigma \Phi^{-1}(1-\epsilon)
$$

My question is what we can say about the same problem in a higher dimension, for example 2, where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are correlated.

$$
\mathcal{P}(a_1 \leq x_1 , a_2 \leq x_2 ) \ge 1 - \epsilon
$$

Comment: 1. where did $\mu$ go? 2. can you apply a linear transformation to eliminte the correlation?

Comment: @LinAlg $\mu$ was missed, it is fixed now.

Comment: This problem won't have a closed-form solution in dimension $d\geq2$, even in the uncorrelated case, I don't think. It can be evaluated numerically.

Comment: @DavidM. in uncorrelated case, I think we can simply decouple the problems into several one dimension problem and solve them respectively.

Comment: I think you would still end up with a product of CDFs, which I don't think you could invert analytically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer (too long for comment). You can evaluate the bivariate normal CDF numerically (using *e.g.* Python and Scipy, which is what I did). We see that, even in the correlated case, the feasible region is convex, which is a hopeful sign, computationally (basically the CDF of the bivariate normal distribution is quasi-convex).

For these numerical examples, I took $\mu_1=\mu_2=0$, $\sigma_1=0.2$, $\sigma_2=0.4$ and covariance matrix
$$
\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1^2 & \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2\\\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\rho\in[0,1]$ is the correlation parameter. Here's $\rho=0.5$, with $\varepsilon=0.4$.

[image: feasible region for rho=0.5]

The simplest naive approximation to this region would be
$$
x_i\geq\mu_i+\Phi^{-1}(1-\varepsilon)\sigma_i.
$$
In general, this approximation isn't great:
[image: poor linear approximation]

But, counter-intuitively (to me), this approximation seems to be exact in the limit $\rho\to1$. Here's $\rho=0.99$:
[image: good linear approximation]

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.